# How can I get specific data from an intermediate table (many to many) in laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to obtain the data that belongs to a specific query object within an intermediate table (many to many) called query_question that is linked between the query - question models.
This is the relationship found in the query model.

```
public function getQuestions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class)->withPivot('sub_test_id', 'test_id', 'score', 'answer');
    }
```

This is the relationship found in the question model

```
public function getQueries(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Query::class)->withPivot('sub_test_id', 'test_id', 'score', 'answer');
    }
```

This is my many-to-many migration scheme

```
Schema::create('query_question', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('question_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('query_id')->unsigned();

            $table->bigInteger('sub_test_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('test_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('query_id')->references('id')->on('queries')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade'); 

            $table->foreign('sub_test_id')->references('id')->on('sub_tests')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('test_id')->references('id')->on('tests')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->unique(['question_id', 'query_id']);
            $table->double('score');
            $table->string('answer');
        });
```

Here I am trying to get the data belonging to a query model object to save all the data related to the query object to an array, but I always get null.

```
$answers = array();
            foreach ($query->getQuestions as $answer) {
                array_push($answers, $answer->pivot);   
            }
```

Here you can see dd($query);
[dd($query)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bcT1.png)

Here the same in text

```
App\Query {#1380 ▼
  #table: "queries"
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  +timestamps: true
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:5 [▼
    "patient_id" => "2"
    "query_type" => "dd"
    "updated_at" => "2021-09-06 16:31:21"
    "created_at" => "2021-09-06 16:31:21"
    "id" => 4
  ]
  #original: array:5 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "getQuestions" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1381 ▼
      #items: []
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

[Database records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tHP0.png)

Comment: Have you ```dd($answer)``` ?

Comment: yes, I also get null when using dd in $answer and $query->getQuestions, however when using dd in $ query if I get a query model object :/

Comment: could you add `dd($query)` to the question ?

Comment: ok, I already edited it, you can see the dd ($ query);

Comment: So it has no items in getQuestions! 
are you sure you have items for this record in that table?

Comment: yes bro, i already edited again, you can see the imagen record's database, query_id 4 exists.

Comment: i'm sorry, but from your dd results, how is there an `patient_id`?